# ScrollY addclass after 100vh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a reactjs project and was wondering how I would be able to change ScrollY `px` values to something like `vh`.

```
state = {
  isTop: true,
};

componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const isTop = window.scrollY < 100;
    if (isTop !== this.state.isTop) {
        this.setState({ isTop })
    }
  });
}
```

Where I am adding/removing class:

```
<NavItem className={this.state.isTop ? 'hide' : 'show fadeIn'}>
  <NavLink href="/">Logos</NavLink>
</NavItem>
```

Right now I add a class after 100px. But, is it possible to add the class after you scroll through 100vh or the viewport height?

Comment: `vh` you can use only in css, jsdom didn't work with this

Comment: Right, is there an equivalent in js?

Comment: Have you tried `window.outerHeight` ?

Comment: No, not really, but `window.innerHeight` allows you to calculate the relative height yourself :)

Comment: `1vh` is (roughly speaking) `window.innerHeight/100` (or maybe `outerHeight`)

Comment: i think most close https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Thanks, i'll try `window.outerHeight`

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was unaware of `window.outerHeight` but it worked really well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.outerHeight` is what you are looking for if you run into this issue.

Solution:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    width: 0, 
    height: 0
  };
  this.updateWindowDimensions = this.updateWindowDimensions.bind(this);
}

state = {
  isTop: true,
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.updateWindowDimensions();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
  document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const isTop = window.scrollY < window.innerHeight;
    if (isTop !== this.state.isTop) {
        this.setState({ isTop })
    }
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
}

updateWindowDimensions() {
  this.setState({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight });
}
```